# Swift Combine Future wrong thread in test

Tags: swift, combine

I have a test where I expect that the sink cllosure is called in the same thread as the one in the future's closure but it doesn't happen always, if a run it 100 times around 8 times it will fail.

```
let expectation = expectation(description: "")

let future = Future<Void, Error> { future in
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        future(.success(()))
    }
}

future.sink(receiveCompletion: { value in
}, receiveValue: { _ in
    XCTAssertNotEqual(Thread.current, Thread.main)
    expectation.fulfill()
})
.store(in: &cancellables)

waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0)
```

This doesn't happen with a `PassthroughSubject`, I have found out it only happens when using a `Future`.

I found a workaround by adding a print statement inside the async closure code:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print(Thread.current)
    future(.success(()))
}
```

It seems like a XCTest bug so I reported it in the FB13358522 ticket, I open this issue in case anyone founds a better solution/workaround.

Reproduced with Xcode 14.2 (14C18) and Xcode 15 (15A240d)

Here is an example of the code using a `PassthroughSubject` where it runs successfully.

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Error>()

subject.sink(receiveCompletion: { value in
    XCTAssertNotEqual(Thread.current, Thread.main)
    expectation.fulfill()
})
.store(in: &cancellables)

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    subject.send(())
    subject.send(completion: .finished)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to be rude answering questions. `receive(on:)` lets the subscriber determine in which queue it should receive the stream but the publishers (Future) can do anything on other threads, you can see an example of a Future+GCD in the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future

Comment: Your assumption that the sink should be called on the same thread as the future closure is a poor assumption.  You also cannot determine if something is running in the Main execution context by checking that it is running on Thread.main as it could also be running on a dispatch queue that targets the main queue (see comments on dispatch_assert_queue)